# Spring Security: change authorities after log-in

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to change the authorities of the currently logged-in user, but I can't make it work.

I'm following this post (at the bottom, the OP claims to have found the solution): http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/60663-change-user-logged-authorities-on-the-fly

My implementation of UserDetails::getAuthorities generates a Collection of authorities according to the inner state of the User, and returns it (I don't use an attribute to hold it):

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    if (... some condition ...) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_A"));
    } else {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_B"));
    }

    return authorities;
}
```

My code for refreshing the authorities:

```
System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities());

SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();

UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("john.doe@example.com");
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken newAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());

context.setAuthentication(newAuthentication);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities());
```

The console output (which is the expected):

```
[ROLE_A]
[ROLE_B]
```

**The problem**: The new authorities are not persisted. When I invoke a service later, the authorities are [ROLE_A], instead of [ROLE_B].